# String Data seems to be deleted after for loop

Tags: c++, arrays, string, data-loss

In the following code, whenever I go to the debugger , the value for paragraph is deleted , or returned to 0 , I can't seem to figure out why, thoughts?

```
void getFreqLetter(string paragraph){
    char alphabet[26] = { 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
    int counter[26];
    //set counter values to zero
    for (int clear = 0; clear < sizeof(counter) - 1; ++clear){
        counter[clear] = 0;
    }
    cout << paragraph;
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(paragraph); ++i){
        //case:found
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(alphabet) - 1; ++j){
            if (alphabet[j] == paragraph[i]){
                counter[j]++;
            }
        }
        //go through array find largest value
        for (int k = 0; k < sizeof(counter) - 1; ++k){
            if (counter[k] > result){ result = counter[k]; }
        }
        cout << result;
    }
}
```

Comment: `sizeof(paragraph)`? Should this not be `paragraph.size()`?

Answer (score 3):

In summary, all the problems are due to your misusing `sizeof`.

`sizeof(paragraph)` is not doing what you think it's doing: it is returning the size of the `string` class, not the number of characters in the string instance.

You should use `paragraph.size()` instead assuming it's a `std::string` type.

`sizeof(alphabet)` returns the number of elements in the array by a lucky coincidence: `sizeof(char)` is **defined** by the standard to be 1. Such "ace" code ought to have a comment attached to it!

You're not so lucky with `sizeof(counter)`. The value you're getting back is a multiple of `sizeof(int)` which varies from platform to platform (2, 4, and 8 are common). You should write either `sizeof(counter) / sizeof(int)` or `sizeof(counter) / sizeof(counter[0])`. The latter is preferred by some folk since you don't need to hardcode the type and since zero length arrays are disallowed by the C++ standard, `counter[0]` is well-defined.

(Something to bear in mind here is that `sizeof` is evaluated at compile-time).

Answer (score 3):

Easy. your `sizeof(counter)` in the loop condition is actually `sizeof(int) * 26`, so your alphabet is crushed by your loop (from iteration 27 on), and some of the stack also (setting the return address to 0 in particular, and the internals of the `paragraph` parameter).

And your `- 1` should not be there, since you're using strict comparison.

You may want to trace through the first loop and observe the value of `sizeof(counter)`.

If you want the number of elements in your `counter` array, an idiomatic way of having it is `sizeof(counter) / sizeof(counter[0])`.

Also, the length of the `string` should be obtained by `paragraph.size()`, because `sizeof(paragraph)` returns the size of the object managing the string, not the string itself.

Finally, the `sizeof(alphabet)` does the right thing, because `sizeof(char)` is defined as 1.

**And now, for some C++11 magic:**

```
#include <array>

const std::array<char,26u> alphabet{ 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 
    'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 
    's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' };
std::array<int, 26u> counter;
//set counter values to zero
for (int clear = 0; clear < counter.size(); ++clear){
    counter[clear] = 0;
}
```

This removes many (all) of the `sizeof` traps, while being as efficient.

Comment: +1 for pointing out the difference between sizeof(char) in C and C++. How many times have I fallen for this one!

Comment: No, you're safe due to your division.

Answer (score 0):

This code

```
//set counter values to zero
for (int clear = 0; clear < sizeof(counter) - 1; ++clear){
    counter[clear] = 0;
}
```

is invalid and results in memory overwrite.

Either use

```
for (int clear = 0; clear < sizeof( counter ) / sizeof( *counter ); ++clear){
    counter[clear] = 0;
}
```

or

```
for (int clear = 0; clear < 26; ++clear){
    counter[clear] = 0;
}
```

or

```
std::memset( counter, 0, 26 * sizeof( int ) );
```

or simply initialize the array by zeroes when you declare it

```
int counter[26] = {};
```

This loop

```
for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(alphabet) - 1; ++j){
    if (alphabet[j] == paragraph[i]){
        counter[j]++;
    }
```

is also invalid. Character array `alphabet` does not contain the terminating zero. So the loop shall be written as

```
for (int j = 0; j < sizeof(alphabet); ++j){
    if (alphabet[j] == paragraph[i]){
        counter[j]++;
    }
```

And this loop is invalid

```
for (int k = 0; k < sizeof(counter) - 1; ++k){
    if (counter[k] > result){ result = counter[k]; }
}
```

See above.

You would not make errors if you would use named constant for magic number 26.

For example

```
const int N = 26;

char alphabet[N] = 
{ 
   'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 
   'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z' 
};

//...

for ( int j = 0; j < N; ++j )
{
        if (alphabet[j] == paragraph[i]){
            counter[j]++;
}
```

To find the largest number you could use standard algorithm `std::max_element` declared in header `<algorithm>`. For example

```
int ewsult = *std::max_element( counter, counter + 26 );
```

Comment: THanks! that fixed everything.